# How to update APK without send the whole file again

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Here's the problem, I have a unity-Android Game and every time I have to upload the update the only way I find send the update is by sending the whole APK again and this sucks because users have to download the whole game again.
My app size is 13MB, and every time I update it that size is what the users download.
I ask this already but the way they tell me to solve this is by using AssetsBundles but, this is a very different way that the one I see other games or apps in the store use because AssetsBundles doesn't include the store and is like a update without the users know.
The way I need is like others apps do, an this is by uploading the part of the APK that is going to add on the app, but I don't find the way.

Answer (score 2):

Apk extensions is maybe what you're looking for. But for the size of your app I wouldn't worry.

Just let them download the whole apk again everytime.

Comment: You don't that will be a problem ? Because it will be increasing memory

Comment: it wont be a problem. APK extensions work like this: you divide your apk in 2 or 3 parts, 1 part contains the code of the apk and the others the assets like levels, meshes, images etc (afaik, never used them myself)

Comment:  thank you Men! I will do a  research about that to can aplicate It 